# How to detect and track shadows in videos

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I'm working with videos of eyes surgeries in which both a surgical tool and its shadow appear; the frames have a very peculiar light condition due to the surgical torch used to lit the area where to operate.
I'm trying to detect the shadow of the tool to be able to track it from one frame to its subsequent but I'm having no success.
What are the most effective and most common techniques to detect shadows?

I tried thresholding to isolate darker areas, CLAHE to enhance contract and I tried to use different colorspaces that better divide intensities and brightness. I also tried background subtraction.

I'd like to have a binary map of the shadow or a list of keypoints lying on the shadow to be able to detect and track it.
[This is an example of the frames I'm working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8qqt.png) - [This is another frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqWXP.png) - [And another one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsGYB.png)

As you can see, shadow is not always present in the frame and sometimes it is not-so-sharp.

[This is a gif of a video I'm working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Dwfr.gif) - Just focus on the light condition and the shadow, the quality is very low because I compressed it to make it a GIF, the real videos is FullHD.

Following, the code snippet used for BackgrounSubtractMOG2:

```
def run(video_src):
    cam = cv.VideoCapture(video_src)

    cam.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS, 10)

    subtractor = cv.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(detectShadows=True)
    frame_idx = 0
    l_edge, r_edge = 0, -1
    while True:
        _, frame = cam.read()

        if frame_idx == 0:
            l_edge, r_edge = crop(frame)
            frame_idx += 1
        frame = frame[:1000, l_edge:r_edge, :]

        fgMask = subtractor.apply(frame)

        cv.imshow('FG Mask', fgMask)
        cv.imshow('Frame', frame)

        cv.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the eye doesn't move, you can use [BackgroundSubtractorMOG2](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_bg_subtraction/py_bg_subtraction.html)

Comment: I already tried that with no results: the outcome was a completely grey image or a mask of the black circular area in the frame (i.e. the microscope lens). I used it as it is delivered with OpenCV, I don't know if there's any parameter that can be tuned.

Comment: @Mattia, could you show your code with it? Also, could you show us some videos? Maybe convert them to GIFs using ffmpeg and upload to same imgur.

Comment: I just added a GIF as you suggested. Wrt to code, it is really messy since it's just a bunch of attempts; moreover, it just contains standard calls to OpenCV functions, with no tuning or pre-processing.

Comment: @zteffi I fixed the problem with the grey images, now I have a feasible output from backgroundsSubtractorMOG2; however, the quality isn't good enough to be used for tracking. I had the related code snippet and the results.